# Apply different color scheme to groups in excel output based on conditional formatting in R

Tags: r, excel

I have a data frame that I am outputting as an Excel file with conditional formats. I want the colors of the conditional formats to change based on the group.

Suppose I have this example data:

```
# A tibble: 9 × 3
  Group Category1 Category2
  <chr> <chr>     <chr>    
1 A     1C        1C       
2 A     1C        1C       
3 A     1C        1C       
4 B     2D        3B       
5 B     2D        3B       
6 B     2D        3B       
7 C     3E        3E       
8 C     3E        3E       
9 C     3E        1A
```

Which can be replicated with this:

```
data <- structure(list(Group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", 
"C"), Category1 = c("1C", "1C", "1C", "2D", "2D", "2D", "3E", 
"3E", "3E"), Category2 = c("1C", "1C", "1C", "3B", "3B", "3B", 
"3E", "3E", "1A")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

I want to apply a conditional format to all columns when `Category1 != Category2`, and I want that color to change based on the group. This is what I have so far, without the grouping variable:

```
library(openxlsx)

wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, sheetName ='Changes')
writeData(wb, sheet = 'Changes', x = helpData)

# conditional formatting style
changeDetected <- createStyle(fontColour = 'black', bgFill = '#FFE663')

conditionalFormatting(wb,
                      sheet = 'Changes',
                      cols = 1, # column A
                      rows = 2:(nrow(helpData)+1), # apply to all rows
                      rule = 'B2<>C2',
                      style = changeDetected)

conditionalFormatting(wb,
                      sheet = 'Changes',
                      cols = 2, # column B
                      rows = 2:(nrow(helpData)+1), # apply to all rows
                      rule = 'B2<>C2',
                      style = changeDetected)

conditionalFormatting(wb,
                      sheet = 'Changes',
                      cols = 3, # column C
                      rows = 2:(nrow(helpData)+1), # apply to all rows
                      rule = 'B2<>C2',
                      style = changeDetected)


saveWorkbook(wb, 'Changes.xlsx', TRUE)
```

This will highlight the rows where the change is detected in yellow, as shown below:

[image]

Is there somewhere in this code, or another way, where I can apply the grouping variable, so that each group gets a different color?

Comment: Please include the `library()` calls when you post some code (**openxlsx** here, I think).

Answer (score 1):

You could include the group variable into the conditional formatting rule. Something like this:

```r
library(openxlsx2)
data <- structure(
  list(
    Group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
    Category1 = c("1C", "1C", "1C", "2D", "2D", "2D", "3E", "3E", "3E"),
    Category2 = c("1C", "1C", "1C", "3B", "3B", "3B", "3E", "3E", "1A")
  ),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
  row.names = c(NA, -9L)
)

# colors for unique groups
grps <- unique(data$Group)
clrs <- palette()[seq_along(grps)] # or use rgb(i, 1, 1) or something alike

# create workbook add data
wb <- wb_workbook()$add_worksheet()$add_data(x = data)

# add conditional formatting to each column
for (i in seq_along(grps)) {
  
  wb$add_dxfs_style(name = grps[i], bg_fill = wb_color(clrs[i]))
  rule <- sprintf("AND(B2<>C2, A2=\"%s\")", grps[i])
  grp <- grps[i]
  
  wb$add_conditional_formatting(
    dims = wb_dims(x = data, cols = "Group", select = "data"),
    rule = rule,
    style = grp
  )
  
  wb$add_conditional_formatting(
    dims = wb_dims(x = data, cols = "Category1", select = "data"),
    rule = rule,
    style = grp
  )
  
  wb$add_conditional_formatting(
    dims = wb_dims(x = data, cols = "Category2", select = "data"),
    rule = rule,
    style = grp
  )
}

if (interactive()) wb$open()
```